# How do I override Bootstrap's <blockquote> border-left with a FontAwesome icon in CSS?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

When a `<blockquote>` appears within my div, I would like to override it so that it uses FontAwesome's `icon-quote-left` as opposed to the `border-left: 5px rgb....` value it uses now.

How can I do this using just CSS?

I don't want to use JS - because it adds too much load to the page.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do this with a CSS Pseudo element.  Here's a JSFiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/cvADH/

```
/* Override the bootstrap style */
blockquote {
    border-left: none;
}

/* Insert the pseudo element - replicating what FontAwesome does */
blockquote:before {
    content: "\f10d"; 
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: What is the `\f10d`? Where did you get that from?

Comment: Oh that's the CSS content value for that particular icon - http://astronautweb.co/snippet/font-awesome/ - awesome. Thanks. This is just what I wanted!

Comment: and how can we do it on the blockquote with pull-right please?

Comment: @qwertzman with the following mirrored code from the pull-left specified above: blockquote:after {
    content: "\f10e"; 
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

Answer (score 0):

Sorry on iPad so can't give a precise answer, but the logic would be to open up bootstrap CSS find the precise place where the icon for the blockqote is declared and override it with your proper CSS which will probably work out to something like disabling bootstrap styles background image/position, switch font-family, and probably add a content: 'char' that injects the character that corresponds to the font awesome character.

---

Update:
See here how it's done

FontAwesome

```
.icon-glass:before { content: "\f000"; }
```

https://github.com/malarkey/320andup/blob/master/less/font-awesome.less

BootStrap

```
.icon-glass { background-position: 0 0; }
```

https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/less/sprites.less

Comment: I would love to see some code on how to achieve this. I know the theory, it's just the syntax and actually doing it - I am dumbfounded by :)

Comment: No PC at hand so no examples.. But look up 320up framework, I know they did a drop in replacement of bootstrap icons in favor of font awesome ones. Maybe looking at their code will help you out

Comment: update with links to examples, the rest should be easy :) ..long version short: download bootstrap, replace sprite.less with font-awesome.less ..rebuild, enjoy.